# how to add Search box on my site?

Tags: php, html

How can i add a search box which uses google to search pages in my website? How can I display the result or how does the google result handled by default?

Comment: https://www.google.com/work/search/products/gss.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not a question for SO. Have a look at the [help] for tips on how and what to ask

Comment: Check this page https://cse.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 0):

From: [Google search on fly](https://cse.google.com/cse/tools/create_onthefly)

Copy and paste this code in your HTML.

```
<!-- Use of this code assumes agreement with the Google Custom Search Terms of Service. -->
<!-- The terms of service are available at http://www.google.com//cse/docs/tos.html -->
<form name="cse" id="searchbox_demo" action="https://www.google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cref" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="" />
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https%3A%2F%2Fcse.google.com%2Fcse/tools/onthefly?form=searchbox_demo&lang="></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But i don't get the results(which will be the pages in my website). I am getting a blank google page.